# Addition to a variable reaches condition border, yet conditionied behavior doesn't take place

Tags: javascript

The purpose of the following script is to count the number of tries a user answered wrong (filled in a wrong password as value). After the "tries" variable went from 0 to 2, the error variable becomes 1 and the user is moved out from the form's webpage.

I tried to use conditionals to establish a flow of that process but these seem to fail in the sense that wrong password won't get the user out of the site and the correct password isn't recognized.

I seem to have a logical mistake I might lack some knowledge to find for now and it feels sour.

As a beginner I ask, what's wrong in the conditional system?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
  Enter password to continue: <br>
  <input type="text" id="user"/>
  <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Enter site"/>
  </form>

  <script>
   document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = function() {
    let tries = 0;
    let error = 0;
    let password = 'tiesto';
    let passwordValue = document.querySelector("#user").value;

    if (passwordValue === password) {
     document.location = 'http://www.maariv.co.il';
    } else {
     tries++;
     alert('Try again please.');
    }

    if (tries === 2) {
     error++;
    }

    if (error === 1) {
     document.location = 'http://www.microsoft.com';
    }
   };
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Password logic is concerning here. You need to test against a database. `!==`

Comment: Hmm, this is from an exercise I had. I would thank you for elaborating why it is problematic if the comparison is positive and not negative in case of a password? To me, I just say" `If the two factors are matching, do stuff` but please tell me why you find this problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dij, and Evelyn Ma, I now understand my mistake.

I didn't realize invoking a function on an event (such as onload) necessites taking all variables **set to 0 or a string** out of the function so these won't be changed by function execution:

Each time the event is triggered and the function executed, the values will be resetted if declared inside the function so the level set in the condition will never be reached.

For example: When var tries set to 0 outside the function, the user could try up until, say, 3 tries and in each execution the var won't be resetted but if it's inside the function it will go back from 1 to 0 each try.

I also had 2 other unrelated mistakes in the code:

1. besides moving all variables set to 0 or a string outside, I had to include the `querySelector` inside to check it's value each time anew.
2. I didn't use return, and in a specific correct way.

Note: Passwords shouldn't be on the code but be called from Database, but this is just an exercise.

Here's the full working exercise code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
        Enter password to continue: <br>
            <input type="text" id="passwordInput"/>
            <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Enter site"/>
        </form>
        <script>
            let tries = 0;
            let error = 0;
            let password = 'tiesto';

            document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = ()=> {

                let passwordInput = document.querySelector('#passwordInput').value;

                if (password === passwordInput) {
                    return window.location.href = 'http://maariv.co.il';
                    } else {
                        tries++;
                        alert('Try again please.');
                    }

                    if (tries === 3) { // 3 is the border.
                        error++;
                    }

                    if (error === 1) {
                        window.location.href = 'http://microsoft.com';
                    }
                };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function you are intializing `tries` to 0, so it becomes 0 each time the function is called and after increment becomes 1, and it never reaches 2 you can declare `tries` outside the function, something like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    Enter password to continue: <br>
    <input type="text" id="user"/>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Enter site"/>
    </form>

    <script>
        let tries = 0;
        document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = function() {

            let error = 0;
            let password = 'tiesto';
            let passwordValue = document.querySelector("#user").value;

            if (passwordValue === password) {
                document.location = 'http://www.maariv.co.il';
            } else {
                tries++;
                alert('Try again please.');
            }

            if (tries === 2) {
                error++;
            }

            if (error === 1) {
                document.location = 'http://www.microsoft.com';
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You put `let tries = 0;` in the onclick funtion, so it will be set to 0 everytime, never reach 2, so just move it out of the function.

```
      let tries = 0;
        document.querySelector("#myButton").onclick = function() {
            let error = 0;
            let password = 'tiesto';
```